# Is there an alternative function to cv2.VideoCapture.set()?

Tags: python, performance, opencv, computer-vision, coding-efficiency

I was testing code performance of my algorithm with line profiler
`%lprun -f track()`

```py
Timer unit: 1e-06 s (µs)

Total time: 1724.82 s

   Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   ==============================================================
   138         1      35075.0  35075.0      0.0    video = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_path)
   139         1          6.0      6.0      0.0    frame_i = 0
   142                                           
   143       927       4004.0      4.3      0.0    for img in frames:
   144       926     294117.0    317.6      0.0        print('Percentage of video processed : {}'.format(round( (currentFrame / total) * 100, 2)))
   145                                                 # capture frame-by-frame
   146       926  545906580.0 589531.9     31.7        video.set(1, currentFrame);
   147                                                 # ret, img = video.read()
   148       926       9046.0      9.8      0.0        frame_i += 1
```

and got suprised with `video.set(1, currentFrame)` taking **31.7%** of the time (**545.9 seconds**).

 What exactly does this function do, and is there a replacement so I can save some 9 minutes?

EDIT here is the whole [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0dXjllh8uCvoZmJeHCsrLSCavXsxzuA/view?usp=sharing) with line profiler

Comment: You ran some code we can't see and it was slow. Please show your code if you'd like some assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set(1, ...)` means `cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`. You **should** use the named constant, not the magic number.

What this does is called "seeking" in the video file.

Seeking in a video file is costly because one has to find the nearest previous keyframe and then decode possibly multiple frames until the desired point. Any library has to spend the effort. This is not the fault of OpenCV.

If you want seeking to be as fast as possible, you must transcode the video into an intra-only format. Then, only the specific frame has to be decoded. You can use H.264 without B- or P-frames (only I-frames), or you can use MJPEG.

In general you should **avoid** seeking. Read the video frame by frame, don't jump around, not even "to the next frame".